# How can I utilise the whitespace in Kendo Scheduler against a resource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm looking into Telerik (JQuery UI) [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-vertical) on the Scheduler component they offer. The `dataSource` bound to the scheduler has a resource of `Meeting Room 101`. As seen in this demo, the width of this is extensive and contains much white space that could contain additional features.

Currently, through-out the documentation, I can only see one way to add resource and attach them to others, that being:

```
resources: [
    {
        field: "roomId",
        name: "Rooms",
        dataSource: [
            { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#2572c0" },
            { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f8a398" }
        ],
        title: "Room"
    },
    {
        field: "attendees",
        name: "Attendees",
        dataSource: [
            { text: "Alex", value: 1 },
            { text: "Bob", value: 2 },
            { text: "Charlie", value: 3 }
        ],
        multiple: true,
        title: "Attendees"
    }
]
```

Now, both the Meeting Room n and Alex/Bob/Charlie contains mass white space. Adding HTML into the `text` ie: `{ text: "Meeting Room 101 <div class='someExtraContent'></div>" }` is not possible. In-fact, it results in something like this:

[image: Kendo Dojo]

Where the HTML is escaped to text. Is it possible to utilise this whitespace without overriding Kendo? Ofc, the solution above is as it would yield horrible search results.

Can any advise on how I can utilise this whitespace with additional content?

Comment: not sure how usful this ideas is so just putting it out there but you could  override their CSS with your own to remove the extra spacing with something like
" :div.k-event {
    width: 10% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}"
or perhaps use the CSS to add and position some icon to fill up the space, just an idea

Comment: There is probably a tonne of ways to override kendo but I want to work with it, not against it as I cannot be guaranteed that future updates will continue to work otherwise. I appreciate the idea though! @PatrickHume

Comment: I assume you have seen the documentation on customizing the form https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/scheduler/customization/form/editor/ and  https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/scheduler/customization/items/item/  again sorry if this isn't helpful just though it was worth pointing out just encase

Comment: I'm aware of this yes, although I still don't think its possible with vertical resources to do this :) I have over 200 appointments in a single 10 minute gap against one resource in some use cases so this would not help me. All I simply want to do is utilise the white space below the resource title like so: https://imgur.com/a/8NQgfPe @PatrickHume (ignoring design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after raising a ticket, this is possible through templating and can be found in the documentation here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/group?&_ga=2.60294062.244228060.1657095422-1203569827.1645623560#groupheadertemplate

From here, you can add additional content to the template of the name.